# Node queuing jobs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, job-queue

I have a MethodQueue class which enqueue method in queue array and execute them. The tricky part here is that I want to execute one job at a time and next job has to start after some x seconds after previous completed to avoid exceeding request within no time.

So I implemented **MethodQueue** class like this.

```ts
class MethodQueue {
    private queue: (() => Promise<any>)[] = [];
    private isExecuting = false;

    async enqueue(method: () => Promise<any>): Promise<void> {
        this.queue.push(method);
        if (!this.isExecuting) {
            this.executeNext();
        }
    }
    private async executeNext(): Promise<void> {
        if (this.isExecuting) return;
        this.isExecuting = true;
        const method = this.queue.shift();
        if (method) {
            await method();
            this.isExecuting = false;
            setTimeout(() => this.executeNext(), 1000);
        } else {
            this.isExecuting = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have **SendQueue** class with static methods that I use from other files.

```ts
export class SendQueue {
    private static methodQueue = new MethodQueue();

    public static async m1(param1: string, param2: number): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
            SendQueue.methodQueue.enqueue(async () => {
                const result = await Send.m1(param1, param2);
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    }

    public static async m2(param1: string): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
            SendQueue.methodQueue.enqueue(async () => {
                const result = await Send.m2(param1);
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    }

    public static async m3(param1: string, param2: boolean): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
            SendQueue.methodQueue.enqueue(async () => {
                const result = await Send.m3(param1, param2);
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Finally I have **Send** class which has actual code

```ts
class Send {
    public static async m1(param1: string, _param2: number): Promise<string> {
        console.log(`Done ${param1}: ${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}:${new Date().getSeconds()}:${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`);
        return "result from m1";
    }

    public static async m2(param1: string): Promise<string> {
        console.log(`Done ${param1}: ${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}:${new Date().getSeconds()}:${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`);
        return "result from m2";
    }

    public static async m3(param1: string, _param3: boolean): Promise<string> {
        console.log(`Done ${param1}: ${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}:${new Date().getSeconds()}:${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`);
        return "result from m3";
    }
}
```

When I am executing with multiple request Its hit and miss with multiple awaits between calls

```ts
(async () => {
    SendQueue.m1("m1", 1);
    SendQueue.m2("m2");
    SendQueue.m3("m3", true);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    SendQueue.m1("m4", 1);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    SendQueue.m2("m5");
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2500));
    SendQueue.m3("m6", true);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    SendQueue.m1("m7", 1);
    SendQueue.m2("m8");
    SendQueue.m3("m9", true);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 13000));
    SendQueue.m1("m10", 1);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    SendQueue.m2("m11");
    SendQueue.m3("m12", true);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    SendQueue.m1("m13", 1);
})();
```

Output:

[image]

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: Could you explain what the problem is, hit & miss is a little bit vague..

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple potential problems.

First off, you have no `try/catch` around the `await method();`.  So, if that method rejects, you will never set `this.isExecuting = false;` back to false and you will not schedule the next method in the queue.

Second, you do the `setTimeout()`, but if before the timer fires, some other code calls `enqueue()`, then it will call `executeNext()` before that timer fires and then the timer will fire and call it again.  It seems that `executeNext()` needs to know when a timer is already running and not do anything until the timer fires.

Here's a suggested fix for these issues (note I'm not a TypeScript person so you probably have to assign a type to the new `timer` instance variable):

```
class MethodQueue {
    private queue: (() => Promise<any>)[] = [];
    private isExecuting = false;
    private timer = null;

    async enqueue(method: () => Promise<any>): Promise<void> {
        this.queue.push(method);
        if (!this.isExecuting) {
            this.executeNext();
        }
    }
    private async executeNext(): Promise<void> {
        // don't run another method if we're already
        // running one or if one is scheduled to run
        if (this.isExecuting || this.timer) return;
        this.isExecuting = true;
        const method = this.queue.shift();
        if (method) {
            try {
                await method();
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
            } finally {
                this.isExecuting = false;
            }
            this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                this.executeNext();
                this.timer = null;
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            this.isExecuting = false;
        }
    }
}
```